# I want to change the file name after downloading the zip file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## What I want to solve

I want to change the name of the file after downloading the zip. I was trying to figure out how to remove the directory name in the middle of this.

In this case, the intermediate directory name is "output".

I would like to know if there is a better way.

```
2_J000001719_1202テスト/output/WNS_UP用データ.txt
2_J000001719_1202テスト/output/Images/1051687701.jpg
↓
2_J000001719_1202テスト/WNS_UP用データ.txt
2_J000001719_1202テスト/Images/1051687701.jpg
```

## Original Source Code

```
        add_dir_name = "#{order.priority}_#{order.orderno}_#{company_name[0, 15]}"

        Zip::File.open_buffer(obj) do |zip|
          zip.each do |entry|
            ext = File.extname(entry.name)
            file_name = File.basename(entry.name)
            dir_name = File.dirname(entry.name)
            next if ext.blank? || file_name.count(".") > 1
            dir = File.join(add_dir_name, dir_name)
            FileUtils.mkpath(dir.to_s)
            zip.extract(entry, dir + ext) {true}
            file_name.force_encoding("UTF-8")
            new_file_name = "#{dir}/#{file_name}"
            new_file_name.force_encoding("UTF-8")
            File.rename(dir + ext, new_file_name)
            @input_dir << new_file_name
          end
        end
```

## What I tried

I added this method to the source code, but it did not work.

```
new_dir = Dir.glob(dir_name+"/*").last
demdem = new_dir.split('/').last
new_file_name = dir.sub("/" + demdem, "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic function to move all files (recursively) from one dir to another:

```
orig_dir = "2_J000001719_1202テスト/output"
new_dir = "2_J000001719_1202テスト"

def move_all_files(orig_dir, new_dir)
  Dir.glob("#{orig_dir}/**/*").each do |path|
    File.move(path, path.gsub(orig_dir, new_dir))
  end
end
```

Comment: I was able to make it work well with the advice you gave me. Thanks for the advice.